# IF statements in HAML form not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, haml

I have an "*Accept/Reject*" workflow for tasks (created with nested forms via Cocoon). Basically,

**if** 1) the current user is the assignee (`current_user.email == :assignee`), 2) the current user is not the creator (`current_user.email != :creator`), and 3) the task has not been accepted (`true`) or rejected (`false`) i.e. nil (`:accepted != nil`),

**then** 1) show the creator (`:creator`) and 2) the enabled field to accept or reject (`f.select :accepted`)

When I am using these if statements, the fields (creator & accept/reject) are showing regardless of whether the condition is true or false. In addition, I am not allowed to use `current_user.email` in my if statement even though I can print it just fine.

Here's my code:

_task_fields.html.haml (views > projects)

```
.nested-fields
    .field
        = f.label :description
        = f.text_field :description
    .field
        = f.label :done
        = f.check_box :done
    - if (:accepted != nil) && (:creator != nil)
        .field
            = f.label :creator
            = f.text_field :creator, :disabled => true
        .field
            = f.label :accepted, "Accept or Reject"
            = f.select :accepted, options_for_select([nil,['Accept',true],['Reject',false]])
    .field
        = current_user.email
        = f.label :priority
        - if :priority == nil
            = f.select :priority, options_for_select(["None","Low","High"],"None")
        - else
            = f.select :priority, options_for_select(["None","Low","High"],:priority)
    .field
        = f.label :assignee
        = f.select :assignee, User.pluck(:email), :prompt => "Select One"
    = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f, :class => "btn btn-default btn-sm"
```

_form.html.haml (views > projects)

```
= form_for @project do |f|
  .jumbotron
    %h3 Project Settings
    .field
      = f.label :title
      = f.text_field :title

    #category
    .form_row
      = f.label :category
      - if @project.category == "process"
        = f.radio_button :category, "process", :checked => 'checked'
        = "process"
        = f.radio_button :category, "checklist", :checked => @project.category == "checklist"
        = "checklist"
      - else @project.category == "checklist"
        = f.radio_button :category, "process", :checked => @project.category == "process"
        = "process"
        = f.radio_button :category, "checklist", :checked => 'checked'
        = "checklist"

    .field
      = f.label :description
      = f.text_field :description

  - if @project.category == "process"
    %h3 Steps
    #steps
      = f.fields_for :steps do |step|
        %ul.list-group
          = render 'step_fields', :f => step
      .links
        = link_to_add_association 'add step', f, :steps
  - if @project.category == "checklist"    
    #tasks
      = f.fields_for :tasks do |task|
        .jumbotron
          = render 'task_fields', :f => task
      .links
        .jumbotron
          = link_to_add_association 'add task', f, :tasks, :partial => 'projects/new_task_fields', :class => "btn btn-default btn-sm"
  = f.submit
```

projects_controller.rb (just the relevant parts)

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title, :category, :description, tasks_attributes: [:id, :description, :done, :priority, :assignee, :creator, :created_at, :accepted, :completed_at, :_destroy])
    end
```

schema.rb (just the relevant parts)

```
create_table "tasks", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "description"
    t.boolean  "done"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "due"
    t.boolean  "started"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.string   "repeat"
    t.integer  "time_limit"
    t.string   "priority"
    t.string   "assignee"
    t.string   "creator"
    t.datetime "started_at"
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.datetime "paused_at"
    t.datetime "resumed_at"
    t.integer  "time_spent"
    t.boolean  "accepted"
  end

  add_index "tasks", ["project_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_project_id"
```

I can add more files if necessary but I doubt my controller/model seems to be the issue. Thanks and appreciate any input.

Answer (score 4):

```
- if (:accepted != nil) && (:creator != nil)
```

The above statement will always be true, because you are checking if a symbol is not equal to nil which is always true

You should check something like

```
- if (@project.accepted != nil && @project.creator != nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I better understand the logic to the if statement now. However, your solution does not make sense since I am checking on the task. (From _form: '= f.fields_for :tasks do |task|
        .jumbotron
          = render 'task_fields', :f => task'). This means I must operate on the task directly but no syntax I have tried seems to make this work (e.g. '@task', '@project.task', 'task', etc.). I appreciate any further feedback you could provide.

Comment: Heeey @orky, that is so big of you: the guy is helping you out, but without any mind-reading skills he can never have any idea what you mean with "symbols" `:accepted` and `:creator`. He gave you to solution to your problem, now you should be able to fix it. Be kind and give credit where it is due. "You should check something like" means: without any more details you give, I am just guessing what it should be. You should be able to handle it now.

Comment: @nathanvda I don't think I was being rude with my statement as I did my best to express gratitude. If I did insult anyone, I do apologize. I am still new to StackOverflow and find it to be a super helpful community. Humbled to have Cocoon's creator be responding so promptly on such a thread. I'll add more details and give credit more quickly. Thanks!

Comment: It was especially the phrase "your solution does not make sense" which sounded harsh to me. Maybe it is a language thing, or I was a bit grumpy. It seemed to disregard the entire answer. Anyway, when rendering a form, or nested form, `f.object` will point to the object at hand. So instead of the symbol, you should just write  `f.object.accepted`.